# How to find class name with Selenium?

Tags: selenium

I am trying to get the info from a website but failed.

The result (cases) is empty for unknown reason.  Any clues?

Here are the extracts of my codes:-

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
driverPath = "D:\In\Python\selenium\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driverPath)
url = "https://www.hktutorcentre.com/"
driver.get(url)

try:
    listCases = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "list_cases"))
    )

    #search for cases
    cases = listCases.find_elements_by_class_name('layui-col-lg2')
    for case in cases:
        print(case)

finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: Can you please provide the URL?

Comment: Is your issue solved?

Answer (score 0):

You have at least tree problems in your code:

1

```
listCases = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "list_cases"))
```

Even `list_cases` is ID element, it is still not unique

2 `find_elements_by_class_name('layui-col-lg2')`
Here you are not looking for a text, it's just WebElement.

3 Instead of `presence_of_element_located` use `visibility_of_element_located`

4 If you want to get text from element, for example a header, use:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".layui-col-lg2>.box>.content.blue>h1").text
```

Comment: Please accept/upvote if your issue is solved.

Comment: Thankssssssssssssssssssss Vitaliis.  Problem solved. :)

Comment: Please accept(click checkbox)/ upvote is the answer was helpful.